# monacaデバッガーでは正常に見えるのに実機にインストールすると外部リンクが正常に表示されない

Tags: monaca

monacaでランチャーアプリを作成しています。
今回外部リンクの修正を行ったのですが、リンク先がスマホに対応していないサイトです。
以下のようにコードを書き、monacaのデバッガアプリからは正常にサイト閲覧ができました。
実機にインストールすると一部分しか表示されず、ピンチアウトなどもできない状態です。
access originで外部サイトへのリンクは許可設定済みです。
何が原因とかんがえられるでしょうか？
アドバイスいただけると助かります。(URLは＊で伏せ字にしてあります)
＝＝＝以下コード＝＝＝

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="ja">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/common.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="js/save.js"></script>
        <script src="js/cssua.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){
                // Android 2系のposition:fixed非対応端末向けにメニューで対応
                if(monaca.isAndroid === true){
                    if(lowerAndroid(4.0) === true){
                        $('.change').each(function(){
                            $(this).attr('href','menu_' + $(this).attr('href'));
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
            monaca.viewport({width : 640});
            monaca.cloud.Push.setHandler(function(data) {
                if(typeof data.title != "undefined") {
                    $('#info .modal-header h3').text(data.title)
                    $('#info .modal-body p').html(data.message)
                    $('#info').modal('show');
                }
            });
        </script>



        <script>
      /*      function testsample() {
                window.plugins.webintent.startActivity(
                    {
                        action: window.plugins.webintent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        url: 'http://****.com'
                    },
                    function() {},
                    function() {alert('Failed to open URL via Android Intent');}
                );
            }

            function check(){
                if(monaca.isAndroid === true){
                    testsample();
                }else{
                    monaca.invokeBrowser('http://****com');
                }
            }
            */

function goToPage() {
var url = "http://www.***.com/";
window.open(url, '_blank');
}

</script>








        <style>
            * {font-size:130%;line-height:130%;}
            body {
                background-color:#3d3d3d;
            }
            .container-fluid {
                padding-left:10px;
                padding-right:10px;
            }
            .row-fluid {
                margin-top:10px;
                margin-bottom:10px;
            }
            #info {
                width:600px;
                margin-left:-300px;
            }
            .color{
                background-color: #ffffff;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row-fluid color">
                <div class="span12">
                   <!--<img src="img/01_logo.png" />-->
                   <img src="img/HRW_logo_top.png" /　>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <a class="change" href="#" onclick="goToPage();"><img src="img/02_site.png" /></a>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span6">
                    <a class="change" href="browser-03.html"><img src="img/03_news.png" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="span6">
                    <a class="change" href="browser-04.html"><img src="img/04_help.png" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span6">
                    <a class="change" href="browser-05.html"><img src="img/05_sns.png" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="span6">
                    <a class="change" href="browser-06.html"><img src="img/06_support.png" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <a class="change" href="browser-07.html"><img src="img/07_market.png" /></a>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="info" class="modal hide fade">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h3></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

下記のコードを実行するためには、プラグインInAppBrowserを有効にする必要があります。
プラグインの設定画面にて、確認してみてください。

window.open(url, '_blank');