# 外部HPへのリンク

Tags: monaca

全くのMonaca初心者です。初歩的な質問で申し訳ありません。
アプリから外部HPを表示させた後，アプリに戻りたいのですが，下記のコマンドでDebuggerではスマホの戻るボタンで戻るのですが，ビルドするとアプリに戻れません。
戻れるようにするにはどうすればよいかどなたかアドバイスをお願いします。
onclick="window.open('URL', '_blank')
あるいは，
onclick="window.open('URL', '_system')

Comment: InAppBrowserプラグインの追加でビルド後も問題なく動作するようになりました。oTakさん，ありがとうございました。

Comment: 上のコメントは質問に対してつけられていますが、コメントはそれぞれの回答の下にもつけることができますから、そちらを使った方がわかりやすいかと思います。加えて、疑問が解決した際には回答の左側にあるチェックマークをクリックしていただくと、解決済みという印になります。 http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/1736/8000

Answer (score 0):

Monacaで「ファイル」→「Cordovaプラグインの管理」を選択して、InAppBrowserプラグインを有効にして試してみてください。

また、過去の質問にも似たような内容があるので、参考にして試すことも解決策の一つだと思います。

[onsenでボタンを押したら外部リンクに飛ぶようにしたいのですが](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/11106/onsen%E3%81%A7%E3%83%9C%E3%82%BF%E3%83%B3%E3%82%92%E6%8A%BC%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89%E5%A4%96%E9%83%A8%E3%83%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AF%E3%81%AB%E9%A3%9B%E3%81%B6%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8C/11151#11151)

[monacaデバッガーでは正常に見えるのに実機にインストールすると外部リンクが正常に表示されない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6966/monaca%E3%83%87%E3%83%90%E3%83%83%E3%82%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF%E6%AD%A3%E5%B8%B8%E3%81%AB%E8%A6%8B%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AB%E5%AE%9F%E6%A9%9F%E3%81%AB%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E5%A4%96%E9%83%A8%E3%83%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AF%E3%81%8C%E6%AD%A3%E5%B8%B8%E3%81%AB%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84/8065#8065)